# Unable to save model object

Tags: django, django-models, django-views

I have created a object which I am trying to save in Django admin in myapp>Hello. But the object does not get created under 'Hello' when I run the server. How can I fix it? I have also registered my models in admin.py.

models.py:

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
class Foo(models.Model):
    foo_id = models.CharField(max_length=10)

class Hello(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, models.DO_NOTHING)
    foo_id = models.ForeignKey('Foo', models.DO_NOTHING, db_column='foo_id')
    foo_text = models.CharField(max_length=500, default="Hello!")
```

views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render,HttpResponse,redirect
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required

from .models import  User,Foo, Hello
from django.contrib.auth import settings

@login_required

def home(request):
    return render(request, 'index.html')





@login_required
def sendhello() :
    Foos=Foo.objects.all()
    for foo in foos:
        #Hello(user=user, foo_text='hello there', foo_id=foo).save()

        xyz, obj=Hello.objects.get_or_create(user=user, foo_text='hello there', foo_id=foo)
        if xyz is True:
            obj.save()
@login_required
def helloxyz(request):
    user = User.objects.get(id=request.session['id'])
    hellos=Hello.objects.filter(user_id=user)
    print(hellos)
    hellos_list=[]

    for hello in hellos:
        print(hello.hello_text)
        hellos_list.append(hello.hello_text)
    hellos_list.reverse()
    print(hellos_list)

    return render(request,'index.html',{'hellos': hellos_list,})
```

Comment: Your `sendhello` function cannot be a view, because it doesn't accept a request or return a response. So what is calling it? Why are you using `login_required` on something that is not a view?

Comment: @DanielRoseman I want to create object with this data-user=user, foo_text='hello there', foo_id=foo

Comment: That doesn't **in any way at all** answer my question. What is calling this function?

Comment: Sir, I have updated my question.

Comment: Not in any way that's useful. For the third time, what is calling `sendhello`?

Comment: @DanielRoseman Nothing.

Comment: Well then how are you expecting the objects to be created?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, your `sendhello` function is not a view, so it does not get called when you view your site. I will for now just assume you have a JS login dialogue or someting you get inputs from. SO you want to generate DB entries from these inputs that are present (?) in your DB. You could do this by simply calling your generating function from within a view class or function (I recommend to put such non-view helper functions in a seperate file and import them in your view) or outside of views with e.g. django cron.
The simplest would be to just create a new file `utilis.py`, import them in your views with `import myapp.utils` and then call your function at the top of your site view.
Why a sperate file? It is just for better readability, is cleaner when someone else looks at your code and swapping out helpers is a bit easier.
If you have regularly occuring tasks that should best be executed independant from the user loading a specific page, take a look at the django_crontab module, it is really handy. You need to be on a Linux system dough.
I hope that answered your question